# Posted image on a wall is too small using graph api and C#

Tags: c#, image, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-wall

I am trying to post a picture on a page wall with this code:

```
string message = "Some message";
string picture = "http://somesource.com/test.jpg";
string pageToken = "page access toke";
string pageId = "page id";
string PostUri = "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/feed?access_token={1}&";

var request = string.Format(PostUri, pageId, pageToken);


var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("picture={0}&", picture);
sb.AppendFormat("message={0}", message);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

webClient.UploadData(request, bytes);
```

It is works for me. But posted image using graph api has smaller size than the image posted using regular facebook web interface. What should I change in this code to display image with larger size?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `source` from `picture`

```
sb.AppendFormat("source={0}&", picture);
```

`picture` is used to thumbnails.

**UPDATE**
You can also set height and width of the image

```
   sb.AppendFormat("height={0}&", 450);
   sb.AppendFormat("width={0}&", 450);
```